# Wieso or Wieso nicht? As a response to an unresolvable claim?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Given the Statement "*Momentan ist keine Änderung der Wunschrate möglich.*"

Context: I am not sure why that statement was thrown, therefor I want to get more information about it.

What would be the appropriate question to question that statement?

Wieso? or Wieso nicht?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both "Wieso?" and "Wieso nicht?" are fine in this situation.

As a remark, "wieso" (negated or not) is relatively high speech. In everyday language, "warum" (or "warum nicht") would be a little bit more natural.